# How to autoscroll to bottom of tableviewrowdata in tableview titanium alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

I have included my tableviewrow data in tableview in titanium alloy application. how I can reach at last position of tableviewrow data ? I want to scroll down to bottom of page(tableview) when click on UIbutton to load tableviewrow data

Thank you
Raj

Answer (score 1):

use: [ScrollToIndex](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-scrollToIndex)

e.g:

```
var colors = ['orange', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

var scrollToBottom=function(e){
var lastIndex=(colors.length-1);
  $.tableview.scrollToIndex(lastIndex);
};
```

Comment: @RajShah you're welcome Raj, please check correct answer :)

Comment: Yes, I have checked it and scrolling is working for me. I have used scrolling of 10 messages in single window. So if there are 100 of messages in Single tableview, user can do scroll 10 times in that App window. I just felt that scrolling event happening after 1 or 2 sec clicked on button. I am trying to reduce that time so user can feel that quick scrolling after click event.